# VertexArray can't find its vertices functions ( SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm making a simple, gravity based particle system, so I made three classes:

- `ParticleManager`, that store the particle system
- `ParticleSystem`, the VertexArray containing particles with an update function
- `Particle`, a Vertex inheriting from sf::Transformable.

Actually, I'm stuck with `ParticleSystem` update function here's the code:

```
ParticleSystem()
{
    particles.setPrimitiveType(PrimitiveType::Points);
    int indexX = 0, indexY = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < CHUNK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        Particle particle;
        particle.position = Vector2f(indexX, indexY);
        particles.append(particle);
        if (indexX < 100)
            indexX++;
        else
        {
            indexX = 0;
            indexY++;
        }
        force.push_back(0);
    }
}
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < particles.getVertexCount(); i++)
    {
        particles[i].Update();
    }
}
```

The compiler gives an error when calling `particles[i].Update()`, because VertexArray can contain just sf::Vertex;

Any suggestion for implementing that function?

Comment: What error? Undeclared reference? Or Undefined reference?

Comment: Update is not a member of sf::Vertex

Comment: Seems like `particles` is a container of `sf::Vertex`es. Can I see it's declaration? Seems like there's no `Update()` in `sf::Vertex`

Comment: VertexArray particles

Comment: What's the definition of `VertexArray`? I think you should edit your post to add more code.

Comment: It's SFML, it's like "std::vector<sf::Vertex>"

Comment: Well that's the problem. The Update function isnt in sf::Vertex

Answer (score 0):

Make your own vector.

```
std::vector<Particle> particles;
```

Comment: sf::VertexArray cannot be templated

Comment: I tried but then I can't draw it because it has to inherit from sf::Drawable

Comment: So have `Particle` inherit from `sf::Drawable`.